# How do i set "type:module" in nodeJs WS Library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ws

This has been asked a million times and answered a million times. But i still can't find a solution. The code im using is exactly the one in the Library docs usage examples:

```
 import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

I haven't changed one single line of code and this is the **only** code i have in Node Js. But my result is the error : "Warning: to load an es module set type module in the package.json or use the .mjs extension" no matter what.

I **know** the answer is simply to change the "type" to "module" in "package.json" file, i have read this a thousand times. The only problems is: I have like a million package.json files in my NodeJS folder and i have no idea which one i should update. Can someone please help?
I have no experience in NodeJS or WS Library,so any hint or any other solution to my problem is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried the other option -- changing the extension to **.mjs**?

Comment: No, i haven't. And i have no idea on how to do that,sorry. Like i said, i have no prior experience in NodeJS. As i try to save my file and change te extension, it does not have the option to save as **.mjs**. Where can i do it?

Comment: Doesn't your code editor have "Save As..." command? Or you can rename the file later.

Comment: Okay i did it. It is now not giving me the error anymore. It is in fact giving me another one,but it is not related to the other one. Answer the question so i can give you the best answer, you solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggested, if you want to use **ECMAScript** modules in a Node.js application you can either:

- Change the file extension to **.mjs**
- Add `"type": "module"` entry at the top level to the *nearest* **package.json**

At this time Node.js will treat all other forms of input as **CommonJS** modules (where you use `require` to import).

**Note**

This may change in the future, and ECMAScript modules might become the default, so it is recommended to be always explicit, and if you want to use **CommonJS**, use **.cjs** extension or add `"type": "commonjs"` to the (nearest) **package.json** file.